Microsoft Azure Gradle build fails in CI/CD pipeline but succeeds locally due to missing dependency `com.kyanogen.signatureview:signature-view:1.2`
I'm working on an Android project using Kotlin in Android Studio, and I have integrated it with a CI/CD pipeline running on Azure DevOps. When I build the project locally using Android Studio, everything works fine, and the APK is generated without any issues. However, when the build runs in the CI/CD pipeline, it fails with the following error:
Project Structure:

Top-level build.gradle:

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.10"
    repositories {
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.esales"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.5.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            useProguard true
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.kyanogen.signatureview:signature-view:1.2'
}

What I've Tried:
Repository Configuration: I've ensured that the jitpack.io repository is included in both the top-level and module-level build.gradle files.
Manual Build: The build succeeds locally in Android Studio, but fails in the CI/CD pipeline.
Cache: I ran ./gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies locally to mimic the CI/CD environment, and it still worked locally.
Question:
Why does my CI/CD pipeline fail to resolve the com.kyanogen.signatureview:signature-view:1.2 dependency, and how can I fix this issue so that the pipeline build succeeds just like my local build?
Additional Information:
The CI/CD pipeline is running on Azure DevOps.
The local environment is macOS with Android Studio, and the CI/CD environment is Ubuntu.

Can you share your pipeline YAML definition and let us know which step incurs what error message?

Change the line from
implementation 'com.kyanogen.signatureview:signature-view:1.2'

to
 implementation 'com.github.zahid-ali-shah:SignatureView:v1.2'

its working on your local machine since its using a cache you can rebuild it using this command to see that you have the wrong dependecies
./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies

You can also verify it here that the naming has been changed https://jitpack.io/#zahid-ali-shah/SignatureView/v1.2
